# Stop div height expanding too much

Tags: html, jquery, css

As part of a page I am working on, I have got divs that contain hidden content and when you hover over them they will expand and you will be able to view the content. These divs all have the same class name: projectTitle and they are all within another div called project. Now so the project div will be able to expand with the hidden content when it shows I have set the height to min:250px. Everything is working however the original height of "project" is bigger than what I would like it to be. Here's some screenshots to show what it currently is and what I'd like it to be:

Current:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

I think the issue is from the hidden content so it is making up the space as it were for it but is there a way to avoid that? I thought maybe adding something like overflow:hidden would fix my issue but that's not the case. For my animation to work I need to have the height to min-height rather than height or max-height but is there a way to avoid it going as big as it currently is?

My code is below and a js fiddle for it here: https://jsfiddle.net/kfcv4tnb/2/

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

$(".projectTitle").hover(
  //on mouseover
  function() {
    $(this).find(".handoverExpanded").toggleClass('open');

    });
});
```

```css
 

   .header img {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #555;
}

.header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 110px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  
}

#model {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.management {
    background-color: blue; /* Changing background color */
    font-weight: bold; /* Making font bold */
    border-radius: 70px; /* Making border radius */
    padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px; /* Making space around letters */
    font-size: 22px; /* Changing font size */
    color: white;
}

.management ~ .management {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}

.project {
    position: relative;
    top: -70px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: lightgray; /* Changing background color */
    font-weight: bold; /* Making font bold */
    border-radius: 70px; /* Making border radius */
   /* padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px; /* Making space around letters */
    font-size: 22px; /* Changing font size */
    min-height: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
   width: 1830px;
}


.projectTitle {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    width: 350px;
    left: 90px;
    bottom: -110px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px!important;
    padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
}

.projectTitle:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: inherit;
    left: 520px;
    bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 5px 40px 5px
}
.projectTitle:nth-of-type(3) {
    position: inherit;
    left: 950px;
    bottom: 130px; 
}
.projectTitle:nth-of-type(4) {
    position: inherit;
    left: 1380px;
    bottom: 250px; 
}

.arrow1 {
    font-size:80px;
    color: grey;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 355px;
    display: block;
}


.handoverExpanded {
    position: inherit;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 300px;
    left: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.projectTitle:hover > .handoverExpanded {
    display: block;
} */

 .handoverExpanded {
    height:0px;
    -webkit-transition:height, 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    transition: height, 0.5s linear;
}
    .handoverExpanded.open {
    height:70px;
     -webkit-transition:height, 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    } 

     .project.open {
     -webkit-transition:height, 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    transition: height, 0.5s linear;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=header>
  <img id="logo" src="images/logo.jpg">

  <h1 class="title">BUSINESS MODEL</h1>
</div>

<div id = "model">
<div class="management">
    Management Strategy, Goals and Objectives
</div>
<div class="management">HSSEQ</div>
<div class="project">
    <p style="text-decoration: underline">Project Delivery Model</p>
    <div class = "projectTitle">
        <p>Project Handover</p>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>HSSEQ</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Management</p>
        </div>
        <span class ="arrow1">&#8594;</span>
    </div>
    <div class = "projectTitle">
        <p>Project Receipt & Phase Initiation</p>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>HSSEQ</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Management</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Engineering</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Controls</p>
        </div>
        <span class ="arrow1">&#8594;</span>
    </div>
    <div class = "projectTitle">
        <p>Project Execution</p>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>HSSEQ</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Management</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Engineering</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Controls</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Construction</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Commissioning</p>
        </div>
        <span class ="arrow1">&#8594;</span>
    </div>
    <div class = "projectTitle">
        <p>Project Close Out</p>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>HSSEQ</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="handoverExpanded">
            <p>Project Management</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself, my css for the project div now looks like:

```
.project {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: lightgray; /* Changing background color */
    font-weight: bold; /* Making font bold */
    border-radius: 70px; /* Making border radius */
    font-size: 22px; /* Changing font size */
    height: 350px;
    display:inline-block;
   width: 1830px;
   -webkit-transition:height, 1.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: height, 1.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: height, 1.5s linear;
    -o-transition: height, 1.5s linear;
    transition: height, 1.5s linear;
}
```

and then with jquery I am doing:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".projectTitle:nth-of-type(1)").hover(
    function() {
       $(".project").height(500);
    }, function(){
        $(".project").height(350);
    });
    $(".projectTitle:nth-of-type(2)").hover(
    function() {
       $(".project").height(700);
    }, function(){
        $(".project").height(350);
    });
    $(".projectTitle:nth-of-type(3)").hover(
    function() {
       $(".project").height(900);
    }, function(){
        $(".project").height(350);
    });
    $(".projectTitle:nth-of-type(4)").hover(
    function() {
       $(".project").height(500);
    }, function(){
        $(".project").height(350);
    });
});
```

Maybe not the most efficient way, but it works well for me